# Cannot open admin panel of magento 2

Tags: magento2

After migrating the magento 2 project from localhost to live server, th frontend works fine but cannot open backend(AdminPanel) of magento.

Please Help, 
Thanx in advc

Answer (score 0):

- Please change Allowoverride none to Allowoverride All in httpd.conf file of your live server.
- Enable mod_rewrite on Apache
- Clear magento cache
- Check URL entries in core_config_data table(for magento2.1)